# Destacar link da página atual

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html5, css3

Estou implementando um menu no cabeçalho da minha página. Conforme o usuário clica nos botões presentes nesse menu, a página é renderizada logo abaixo. Gostaria de destacar no menu o botão referente a página atual do usuário.

Estou a chamar desta maneira:

```
<li>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", new { controller = "Informativo" })" title="Informativo"> Inf. </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Você já tentou fazer alguma coisa? Teria algum código para poder te direcionar?

Comment: Chamo-os desta maneira: <li> <a href="@Url.Action("Index", new { controller = "Informativo" })" title="Informativo"> Inf. </a> </li>

Answer (score 3):

Num sistema que fiz aqui, usei a `@section Scripts` pra definir uma pequena ação para adicionar uma classe `active` num determinado item, que realça o item.

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#item-qualquer").toggleClass("active");
        });
    </script>
}
```

Isto pode ser feito programaticamente, substituindo o `#item-qualquer` pela identificação de `Action` e `Controller`, por exemplo:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#" + @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]).toggleClass("active");
        });
    </script>
}
```