# Como Estilizar link de Navegação da Página Atual

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
A imagem acima é um *print* do `menu` que estou desenvolvendo que ficou com o estilo que coloquei certinho no CSS. Porém só quando passo o *mouse* por cima do link, ou seja quando faço `:hover` que era o que eu estava fazendo nesse print.

Agora quero configurar para por exemplo:
Clico na `página 1`, aí vai me levar para a `página 1` e o fundo desse mesmo link vai ficar realçado/destacado a verde como no exemplo da imagem acima, mas não na página `Geral`, apenas na página atual pois não estou na página `Geral`, e vice-versa. Como faço?

Comment: [vinculado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70162/11886)

Answer (score 3):

Se estiveres a criar página por página, podes utilizar essa vantagem para fazer isso.
Por exemplo, imaginemos que temos 2 páginas: `index.html` e `sobre.html`, e queremos destacar o link da página atual conforme navegamos de uma para a outra.

Bom, primeiro vamos criar uma class responsável pelo estilo CSS para este link em destaque:

```
.paginaAtual {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#71953E;
}
```

Então agora iremos fazer o seguinte - Na página **index.html** os links de navegação irão ser criados da seguinte maneira:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="linkMenu paginaAtual"><a href="index.html">Index page</a></li>
        <li class="linkMenu"><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Enquanto na página **sobre.html** os links serão criados assim:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="linkMenu"><a href="index.html">Index page</a></li>
        <li class="linkMenu paginaAtual"><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

### Caso o exemplo acima não seja uma opção, eis uma alternativa para isto:

Nesta segunda opção, iremos utilizar JavaScript, mais precisamente a biblioteca jQuery. Para utilizarmos a biblioteca jQuery caso não estejas familiarizado com ela, precisamos de a implementar no `<head>` do nosso documento/website usando a seguinte linha de código:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Esta linha de código acima irá implementar a biblioteca jQuery hospedada pela Google, mas também poderia ser hospedada por ti no teu servidor. Depois então iremos criar o nosso menu:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="linkMenu"><a href="index.html">Index page</a></li>
        <li class="linkMenu"><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
$("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']").addClass("paginaAtual");
```

> Esta linha de código Javascript acima necessita de ser implementada dentro da tag
>   `<script></script>` no teu documento.