# efeito pagina atual css e jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Eu tenho um menu assim:

> **| HOME | NOTICIAS | ABOUT | OUTROS |**

esse menu tem `background` **branco**, mas eu quero fazer o seguinte, se eu estiver na pagina noticias quero que o `background` fique **azul**, igual a esse [tema wp](https://demo.tagdiv.com/newsmag/category/tagdiv-tech/)?

Comment: Se poderia postar o seu código html + css + javascript da sua pagina, suas tentativas ?

Comment: eu já tentei colocar um onload em cada pagina chamando uma função com o id do menu
<script>
function color(menuid){
 var change = document.getElementById(meuid);
 change.style="background:blue;"
}
</script>
<body onload="color=('IdDoMenu')">

Comment: Isto é um site criado apenas com HTML? WordPress? Outro?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como mudar cor do link quando estiver na página do link acessado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119217/como-mudar-cor-do-link-quando-estiver-na-p%c3%a1gina-do-link-acessado) ou possível duplicada de: [Como Estilizar link de Navegação da Página Atual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75899/11886)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma classe que alteraria o estilo da opção ativa no menu, e depois com javascript adicionar essa classe, segue código:

**CSS:**

```
/*Aqui pode ser inserido mais estilos, coloquei só o background para o exemplo*/
.ativo{
    background: blue;
}
```

No `.onload` de cada pagina sera feita a aplicação dessa classe no respectivo item *ativo* do menu. Na pagina home, aplica estilo no botão **HOME**, na página noticias, aplica estilo no botão **NOTICIAS**, e assim sucessivamente... Não é a melhor forma, mas como seu menu é pequeno e o projeto aparenta possuir poucas páginas, não te trará tanto retrabalho.

**JS:**

```
//Exemplo página HOME
window.onload = function(){
    document.querySelector("#home").addClass("ativo");
}

//Exemplo página NOTICIAS
window.onload = function(){
    document.querySelector("#noticias").addClass("ativo");
}
//E assim sucessivamente em cada pagina...
```